# "сукупність" по відношенню до людей

Tags: вибір-слова

> У дослідженні об'єктами вивчення виступала одна і та ж **сукупність** з 50
>   студентів та їхні 5-бальні оцінки за дворазове виконання однієї і тієї ж
>   роботи до і після застосування педагогічного впливу проблемного
>   навчання.

Чи можна використовувати слово "сукупність" по відношенню до людей?

Чи не краще сказати "група студентів"?

Comment: Є статистичний термін [вибірка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3):

Словосполучення «сукупність людей» вживається. Наприклад, бачу [42 трапляння в корпусі GRAC-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword,[lemma=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22]+[lemma=%22%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%22]&corpname=grac3). Але акцент, мені здається, у тих уживаннях інший, наприклад, «всі люди, які підпадають під певні критерії» абощо — але не просто «якась довільна група людей».

Тому у Вашому випадку, мені здається, справді більше підходить «група». (По-моєму, доречно казати, наприклад, «сукупність [всіх] студентів певного навчального закладу», але аж ніяк не «сукупність із 50 студентів» — в останньому випадку слово «сукупність», мені здається, не підходить.)

Comment: Все одно є сумніви... Вживатися може що завгодно, чи не так? Помилки трапляються постійно... Множина людей... Теж якось дивно. Але зі мною можуть не погодитися. Буду вдячна за коментарі з цього приводу.

Comment: @Enguroo, так на мій погляд, у цьому випадку якраз **не** варто вживати слово «сукупність».

Comment: @Enguroo, «множину» я мав на увазі [в математичному сенсі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Множина), а не в побутовому; мабуть, мені варто прибрати з відповіді слово «множина», щоб не було різнотлумачень.